# minimum difference on jquery slider range

Tags: jquery, slider

I've seen several examples of what I am after but nothing that actually answers what I need.

I am changing the value of two elements with the `ui.values` of the slider. The difference between these values cannot be less than '2'.

So I used a quick formula if(x-y<2) dont change else change. But If the difference is less than '2' the slider handlers still move. Anyway to stop this?

```
var sstart = $("#slidestart").text()
var send = $("#slideend").text()

$('#dateSlider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    minRange: 2,
    max: 14,
    step: 1,
    values: [ sstart, send ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.values[1] - ui.values[0] < 2){
                // do not allow change
                alert("that is naughty");
            } else {
                // allow change
                    $("#slidestart").text(ui.values[0])
                    $("#slideend").text(ui.values[1])   
            }   
        }
});
```

Thank you: Perfect result.

```
return false;
```

[JS BIN EDIT](http://jsbin.com/uroxe4/3/edit)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, all you have to do is replace your alert with:

```
return false;
```

Comment: Haha this is the shortest _working_ answer that I've seen all day.

Answer (score 3):

### For future reference

Accepted answer is perfectly valid and should be used in your case, but I will provide an answer as well for any future reference.

I had a bit more constraints so I created an extension on top of the existing jQuery UI Slider widget. It has additional options (some of which are related to minimum and maximum slide range size).

Check out [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/advanced-jquery-ui-range-slider.html) with detailed code.

All changes are related to range slider and include

- setting minimum and maximum range size
- lower range boundary maximum allowed value
- upper range boundary minimum allowed value
- automatic range sliding (when reaching maximum range size dragged handle drags the other handle along to keep max range size)